# U-Boot FASTBOOT flash commands for NOR storage

Tags: linux, spi, u-boot, fastboot, imx6

I would like to know whether it is possible to use fastboot flash/erase commands for a NOR storage. I am using an imx6 processor together with a NOR storage.
Currently "rx_process_flash" function in "cmd_fastboot.c" file supports three storage types.

```
CONFIG_FASTBOOT_STORAGE_MMC
CONFIG_FASTBOOT_STORAGE_NAND
CONFIG_FASTBOOT_STORAGE_SATA
```

However, there is no CONFIG type for NOR storage. Sending a fastboot flash command from the host machine result in the following response from the U-Boot console.

```
Not support flash command for current device 0
send: FAILfailed to flash device
```

Does fastboot provides support for NOR flash? What modifications do I need to do in the U-Boot configuration file in-order to support fastboot for NOR storage?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As a rule you should say what version of (including the vendor release) that you're working from.  That said, no, mainline only supports NAND and MMC and it appears that NXP added SATA support in their tree (CONFIG_FASTBOOT_STORAGE_xxx doesn't exist in mainline).  It should not be hard to add support given that we have fastboot support writen such that the storage medium is decoupled from the protocol itself.  Patches welcome!

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for the reply.